# What does "paid certificate program" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I have recently received an email from my university. I'm referring to the third paragraph.

I received this because I attended a employability soft-skills improvement event.

> Dear Student,
>
> Thank you for participating for this workshop and showing interest in developing your professional skill-set. We hope you had an interesting time and gained valuable knowledge.
>
> Please take a moment to fill out the attached feedback form to be sent to (censored). They are very much interested in having your opinion to further develop their program.
>
> P.S. Please confirm along with the filled form whether you are willing to participate in **a paid certificate program** by (censored) during your semester break at (censored).

Does this mean that I have to pay them or Is it like a paid internship where we get paid.

My guess is we need to pay them, I need some clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think that a "paid certificate program" in this case is a program you pay for that gives you some certificate. For example, I have a certificate that says I know how to perform CPR, and I had to pay for the class that I got that certificate from. I could probably call that class a "paid certificate program."

So I think yes, you need to pay them.